# Grunt task to inject a files contents into a placeholder within another file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a JavaScript file called toInject.js. I would like the contents of this file to be injected into another JavaScript file in the place of a comment placeholder `/* === toInject.js placeholder === */` through a grunt task. What grunt task is available to do this any what configuration is required?

**Both files before grunt task has run:**

toInject.js

```
alert('hello world');
```

myScript.js

```
function doSomething() {
    /* === toInject.js placeholder === */
}
```

**Changes to myScript.js after grunt task has run:**

myScript.js

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamicly set task configs:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-replace');
  grunt.initConfig({
    replace: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          patterns: [{
              match: 'foo',
              replacement: 'bar'   
          }]
        },
        files: [
          {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['src/index.html'], dest: 'build/'}
        ]
      }
   }
});

// register custom task
grunt.registerTask('replaceByFileContents', 'Description', function() {
  // get files 
  grunt.file.expand({cwd: 'src', '**/*.js'}).map(function(file) {
    // set config: replace 'index.js' by index.js content
    grunt.config.set('replace.dist.option.patterns', {
      match: file,
      replacement: grunt.file.read(file)
    });
    // run task
    grunt.task.run(replace:dist)
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What would the config be for my specific scenario?

Comment: Provide list of files contains regexp for `replace` task (`files` property). Then provide list of files for injecting to files from first list (`grunt.file.expand`). Just play with values.